# Permanently set the kubectl cache directory

Tags: windows, caching, kubernetes, kubectl

Due to a number of settings outside of my control, the default location of my kubectl cache file is on a very slow drive on my Windows PC. This ended up being the root cause for much of the slowness in my kubectl interactions.

I have a much faster location in mind. However, I can't find a way to permanently change the location; I must either temporarily alter the home directory environment variables or explicitly set it on each command.

Is there a way to alter my .kube/config file to permanently/persistently set my cache location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way for you is move the whole home directory to fast drive.

But if you don't want moving the whole directory you can [set Powershell alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-6) for your command like 
`PS> Set-Alias -Name kubectl -Value "Path\to\kubectl --kubeconfig=PLACE_FOR_YOUR_CONFIG"`